# SSL CA Cert Issue Preventing GitLab CI/CD Pipeline from Pushing Migrations in Django-Docker Setup

Tags: docker, gitlab, ssl-certificate, gitlab-ci

I am managing a Django project, containerized via Docker, on a self-hosted GitLab server. I've configured a GitLab CI/CD pipeline with three stages: build, migrations, and deploy, orchestrated by a GitLab Runner.

During the migrations stage, the pipeline is designed to create Django migrations, commit them, and push them to the repository. However, I am encountering an SSL CA certification issue when attempting to push the migrations. The error message is as follows:
`fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.teilor.ro/opal/opal-backend.git/': Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)`

Below are the relevant configurations and scripts:

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - build
  - migrations
  - deploy

build_job:
  tags:
    - dev
  stage: build
  script:
    - chmod +x ./scripts/opal_build.sh
    - ./scripts/opal_build.sh
  only:
    - dev
    - master

migrations_on_dev:
  tags:
    - dev
  stage: migrations
  script:
    - chmod +x ./scripts/migrations.sh
    - ./scripts/migrations.sh

deploy_on_dev:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - dev
  script:
    - chmod +x ./scripts/opal_run.sh
    - ./scripts/opal_run.sh
  only:
    - dev
```

opal_build.sh:

```
cp /srv/opal/backend/.env .
cp /etc/gitlab-runner/certs/gitlab.teilor.ro.crt .
docker build -f ./Dockerfile_bullseye -t opal-backend-test .
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo "Docker build failed, exiting."
  exit 1
fi
```

migrations.sh:

```
CONTAINER_NAME="opal-backend_web_test"
PROJECT_DIR="/code"
#REMOTE_REPO="origin"
BRANCH="dev"
TOKEN="Redacted"
# Function to execute upon an error
handle_error() {
    echo "Error on line $1"
    exit 1
}

# Trap any error and call handle_error function
trap 'handle_error $LINENO' ERR

COMMANDS="
cd $PROJECT_DIR && \
cp $PROJECT_DIR/gitlab.teilor.ro.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/gitlab.teilor.ro.crt && \
update-ca-certificates && \
git config --global http.sslCAInfo /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/gitlab.teilor.ro.crt && \
git config user.name 'Gitlab Runner' && \
git config user.email 'daniel.babaian@teilor.ro' && \
git config --get http.sslCAInfo && \
git config --get user.name && \
git config --get user.email && \
git remote add gitlab_origin https://oauth2:${TOKEN}@${CI_PROJECT_URL#https://}.git && \
echo 'Creating migrations...' && \
python manage.py makemigrations && \
echo 'Migrations created.' && \
echo 'Committing migrations...' && \
git add -A && \
git commit -m 'Created new migrations.' && \
echo 'Migrations committed.' && \
echo 'Pushing to remote repository...' && \
echo $CI_JOB_TOKEN && \
echo $CI_PROJECT_URL && \
git push gitlab_origin HEAD:$BRANCH -o ci.skip && \
echo 'Pushed to remote repository.' && \
rm .git-credentials && \
echo 'Applying migrations...' && \
python manage.py migrate && \
echo 'Migrations applied.'
"
docker run -d \
  --name $CONTAINER_NAME \
  --restart always \
  --network app_opal_network \
  -v /srv/opal/backend/volumes/media:/code/media \
  -p 8001:8000 \
  --env-file /srv/opal/backend/.env \
  -e PLATFORM=dev \
  -e TZ=Europe/Bucharest \
  -e REDIS_HOST=redis \
  -e RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq3opal \
  -e RABBITMQ_USER=admin \
  -e RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=Teilor.24 \
  -e PLATFORM=dev \
  opal-backend-test \
  bash -c "$COMMANDS"
sleep 5
docker logs $CONTAINER_NAME
docker container stop $CONTAINER_NAME
docker container rm $CONTAINER_NAME
#docker rmi opal-backend-test
```